# Delegates within class

Tags: vb.net, delegates

I have **ListView** with for loop to fill items, every item created is there an instance of class **TSMPPConnection** and this class have property **ConnectionItem** to hold listView item, I want to change item text from inside class that request come from object event, when I change item text directly it throw exception .

> Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control
>   'lstConnections' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was
>   created on.

**Delegates :**
I used delegate to achieve this but same error.

```
 Delegate Sub dlg_WriteConnectionItemStatus(s As String)
    Sub WriteConnectionItemStatus(s As String)

        Dim dlg As New dlg_WriteConnectionItemStatus(AddressOf WriteConnectionItemStatus)
        dlg.Invoke(s)

        'there is no InvokeRequired to check if execution come from delgate and avoid infinite loop
        If ConnectionItem IsNot Nothing Then ConnectionItem.SubItems(6).Text = s

    End Sub
```

**There is no InvokeRequired to check if execution come from delegate and avoid infinite loop**

Try 1 : Using another sub with same structure to call it from delegate inside original sub.

```
  Delegate Sub dlg_WriteConnectionItemStatus(s As String)
    Sub WriteConnectionItemStatus(s As String)

        Dim dlg As New dlg_WriteConnectionItemStatus(AddressOf WriteConnectionItemStatus_Interface)
        dlg.Invoke(s)

    End Sub

    Sub WriteConnectionItemStatus_Interface(s As String)

        If ConnectionItem IsNot Nothing Then ConnectionItem.SubItems(6).Text = s

    End Sub
```

**SAME ERROR**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must invoke a control or a form, invoking the delegate itself is equal to just calling it directly: `WriteConnectionItemStatus()`.

You can simplify things by creating an extension method for this instead:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module Extensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub InvokeIfRequired(ByVal Control As Control, ByVal Method As Action)
        If Control.InvokeRequired = True Then
            Control.Invoke(Method)
        Else
            Method.Invoke()
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

To use it you must get the parent ListView of the item. If you're targeting **.NET 4.0 or higher** you can use lambda expressions instead of normal delegates, which is easier to write and much more flexible:

```
Sub WriteConnectionItemStatus(s As String)

    If ConnectionItem IsNot Nothing Then _
        ConnectionItem.ListView.InvokeIfRequired(Sub() ConnectionItem.SubItems(6).Text = s)
End Sub
```

However if you're targeting **.NET 3.5 or lower** you have to stick to delegates:

```
Delegate Sub SetSubItemTextDelegate(Item As ListViewItem, Index As Integer, Text As String)

Sub WriteConnectionItemStatus(s As String)

    If ConnectionItem IsNot Nothing Then _
        ConnectionItem.ListView.InvokeIfRequired(New SetSubItemTextDelegate(AddressOf SetSubItemText), ConnectionItem, 6, s)
End Sub

Sub SetSubItemText(Item As ListViewItem, Index As Integer, Text As String) 'Generalized method for flexibility.
    Item.SubItems(Index).Text = Text
End Sub
```